# Boolean value magically changed to false from ViewModel to View

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I need to validate two password fields. If they match then the credential has to be validated in the validation viewmodel. I set a bool value validPassword in the validation viewmodel and need to refer it in the view. Then do something in the view according to validPassword value. However, validPassword always is false when I refer it in the view even though it is true in the viewmodel.

ViewModel:

```
 internal static bool validPassword;
    public static bool CheckCredentials(string username, string password, string domain)
    {
        string userPrincipalName = username + "@" + domain + ".com";


        try
        {
            using(var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
            {
                validPassword = true;
                return context.ValidateCredentials(userPrincipalName, password);
            }
        }
        catch // a bogus domain causes an LDAP error
        {
            errorsForPassword.Add("Invalid Login!");
            validPassword = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Code behind the view:

```
  private void PwBox_OnKeyDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip toolTip = new System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip();
        //PasswordBox passwordBox = sender as PasswordBox;
        passwordAgain = PasswordAgainBox.Password;
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordAgain) || !string.Equals(passwordAgain, MiscParameterViewModel.password))
        {
            PwBoxBorder.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);                
            MiscParameterViewModel.nextButtonIsEnabled = false;
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordAgain))
            {
                toolTip.Content = "Please enter the password again!";
                ToolTipService.SetToolTip(PasswordAgainBox, toolTip);
            }
            else if(!string.Equals(passwordAgain, MiscParameterViewModel.password))
            {
                toolTip.Content = "Passwords don't match!";
                ToolTipService.SetToolTip(PasswordAgainBox, toolTip);
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            //ToolTipService.SetToolTip(PasswordAgainBox, null);
            //PwBoxBorder.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
            _validationViewModel.Authenticate();
            if(!ValidationViewModel.validPassword)
            {
                toolTip.Content = "Invalid password!";
                ToolTipService.SetToolTip(PasswordBox, toolTip);
                ToolTipService.SetToolTip(PasswordAgainBox, toolTip);
                PwBoxBorder.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                PwBoxAgainBorder.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);  
            }
            else
            {
                ToolTipService.SetToolTip(PasswordBox, null);
                ToolTipService.SetToolTip(PasswordAgainBox, null);
                PwBoxBorder.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
                PwBoxAgainBorder.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);  
            }

        }
    }
```

Authenticate is an async method in the viewmodel and it calls CheckCredentials method.

Here is the Authenticate method:

```
  public async void Authenticate()
    {
        MiscParameterViewModel.nextButtonIsEnabled = false;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("NextButtonIsEnabled");
        const string propertyKey = "Password";            
        bool isValid = false;

        /* Call service asynchronously */
        if(MiscParameterViewModel.servServiceLoginType == ServiceLoginTypes.Windows)
        {
            if(errorKeys.ContainsKey(propertyKey))
            {
                errorsForPassword.Clear();
                errorKeys.TryRemove(propertyKey, out errorsForPassword);

                /* Raise event to tell WPF to execute the GetErrors method */
                RaiseErrorsChanged(propertyKey);
            }

            //if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordAgain))
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            {
                errorsForPassword.Add("Login is required!");
                errorKeys.TryAdd(propertyKey, errorsForPassword);

                isValid = false;
            }
            else
            {

                isValid = await Task<bool>.Run(() =>
                {
                    return CheckCredentials(username, password, domain);
                })
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
            }


        }
```

Comment: There is no such thing as *magic*

Comment: "Authenticate is an async" - sounds like it could be a race condition where you hit the validPassword field before the other thread has called CheckCredentials? Maybe post the contents of the Authenticate() method?

Comment: Why does the value get changed then?

Comment: No, it is the only place to call Authenticate now.

Comment: Even if it's the only place, you could still have a race condition. Post your authenticate method and we'll see.

Comment: Just posted Authenticate method.

Comment: I just tried if I skip Authencate method and called CheckCredentials directly it is then right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that your Authenticate method is executing CheckCredentials on another thread, then returning control to your view. What this means is that you will (sometimes) get to this line:

```
if(!ValidationViewModel.validPassword)
```

before CheckCredentials has been called. You're seeing false because that's the default value for booleans - it hasn't been set yet.

You could fix this in a couple of different ways. You could return a Task from your authenticate method, and then call .Wait() on the task before checking validPassword.

Or you could simply remove the async/await from your Authenticate method and make it a synchronous method. Which is right depends on the rest of your application.

Edit: Here's my attempt at your authenticate method. I had to guess on some of the functionality you want.

```
public async Task<bool> Authenticate()
{
    MiscParameterViewModel.nextButtonIsEnabled = false;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("NextButtonIsEnabled");
    const string propertyKey = "Password";

    /* Call service asynchronously */
    if(MiscParameterViewModel.servServiceLoginType == ServiceLoginTypes.Windows)
    {
        if(errorKeys.ContainsKey(propertyKey))
        {
            errorsForPassword.Clear();
            errorKeys.TryRemove(propertyKey, out errorsForPassword);

            /* Raise event to tell WPF to execute the GetErrors method */
            RaiseErrorsChanged(propertyKey);
        }

        //if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordAgain))
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            errorsForPassword.Add("Login is required!");
            errorKeys.TryAdd(propertyKey, errorsForPassword);

            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return await Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(() => CheckCredentials(username, password, domain));
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Once you get the task back, you'll have to decide what to do with it. If you just call .Wait(), it will work, but you'll get the same problem you had where the GUI freezes while you're waiting.

You might want to use the .ContinueWith() method instead, which will be called once the task is complete, and then in there you can update your password box. You might need to marshall the changes back onto the GUI thread (ContinueWith will be on another thread) to set the password box's values - not sure without the complete solution. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. That makes a lot of sense. I don't want to use the second option though if I don't have to. I don't want the program gets freeze a little bit when it is authenticating the credential. I haven't used async much. How can I return a Task from the authenticate method and then call .Wait() before checking validPassword?

Comment: I'll see if I can code something up to make it work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  I will try it tomorrow. Have learned some about async from you here. 